# create a JAR file for plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I try to make my plugin installable so I use the export feature of eclipse.
I use the exporting steps in the MANIFEST page.
I probably do somthing wrong on those setting steps because when I install this plugin it seem like it install fine,but when I tring to use this plug-in only several function works and other not.

Some more info: 
My plugin is using the eclipse hover and add aditional information to the hover.
If I run the plugin as eclipse project everything works fine.
When I try to use the installed one only the setting page (IWorkbenchWindow window) works. When I try to get the hover info I get eclipse error that say:

" Unexpected runtime error while computing a text hover"

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. If there is edit your question to add the details from the .log.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks the error log said about index out of range in one of my function. Probably I did'nt do enough test on my plugin